graphtraversal source issue
2024/07/24 19:00:55 Error occurred during operation gremlinServerWSProtocol.readLoop(): 'E0703: expected string Key for map, got type='0x%!x(MISSING)''
2024/07/24 19:00:55 Read loop error 'E0703: expected string Key for map, got type='0x%!x(MISSING)'', closing read loop.
2024/07/24 19:00:55 Connection error callback invoked, closing protocol.
while connecting to local server working perfectly no issue,
but i had tried to connect dev server by portforwarding, then each traversal query excecution throws error like
